# run program by shortcut in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shortcut

I use "/programy/trinityrnaseq_r2012-06-08/Trinity.pl" for running program of my interest. Instead, I would like just to type "trinity" or eventually "Trinity.pl" into terminal.

How can i do that? I have tried editing my .bashrc with no success. Thanks a lot.

edit: thanks, problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bash and this change only needs to apply to you and not other users or processes on the system, then editing the .bashrc should work.

```
alias trinity=/programy/trinityrnaseq_r2012-06-08/Trinity.pl
```

If you are using a different shell, then the syntax and file name may be different.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Will accept your answer asap :-)

Answer (score 3):

In `~/.bashrc`:

Assuming `Trinity.pl` is excutable:

```
alias trinity="/programy/trinityrnaseq_r2012-06-08/Trinity.pl"
```

If not:

```
alias trinity="perl /programy/trinityrnaseq_r2012-06-08/Trinity.pl"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symbolic links into your `~/bin` directory and put the direcotry into your `$PATH`:

```
ln -s /programy/trinityrnaseq_r2012-06-08/Trinity.pl ~/bin/trinity
```

In your `.bashrc` (if your `bin` is not alrady in `$PATH`):

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```